# Preserve relation (image ratio) of an image with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a theater (Like when you open a facebook image) And I need the image's width to keep the relation when I modify the window's height (And therefore the image's height, as I have the image's height set based on the window's height). If I'm not being clear enough, here's the link to the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmzq32qd/), 'cause one code snippet says more than a thoushand words.

Html:

```
<div id="theater">
 <img src="http://www.lametonesdeamor.com/blog/img/caballofelicisimo.jpg" alt=""></img>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #theater{
    position:fixed;
 }
 #theater img{
    height:100%
 }
```

JS (jQuery) To update the height based on window's height

```
setInterval(function(){ 
$("#theater").height($(window).height()-40);}, 10)
```

Comment: What's the actual question? The fiddle you provided seems to be working as you described.

Comment: Nope... Change the height of the fiddle and the image will shrink...

Comment: In the fiddle: As window height shrinks, the image height shrinks. As the image height shrinks, the image width shrinks to keep the aspect ratio. What do you want the image behaviour to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the height of the img will not trigger a resize of the width in some browsers.  Instead, max-width and max-height will be helpful here:

```
#theater{
    position:fixed;
}
#theater img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Also, you probably want to use the `$(window).resize` rather than resetting the size of #theater 100 times a second:

```
function resizeTheater(){ 
  $("#theater").height($(window).height()-40);
}
$(window).resize(resizeTheater);
resizeTheater();
```

Revised JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmzq32qd/2/

Also, just a note: for proper XHTML syntax, img elements should be closed like this `<img />` rather than like this `<img></img>`

```js
function resizeTheater(){ 
  $("#theater").height($(window).height()-40);
}
$(window).resize(resizeTheater);
resizeTheater();
```

```css
#theater{
    position:fixed;
}
#theater img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="theater">
  <img src="http://www.lametonesdeamor.com/blog/img/caballofelicisimo.jpg" alt="" />    
</div>
```